# Prepopulate a combobox in silverlight 5

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-5.0

I need to pre populate a combobox from the code in Silverlight with values from 1- 10 and the selected value should be 3 by default. How do I do?

```
 private int _Rounds=3;

[RequiredField]
[MultipleChoice]
    public int Rounds
            {
                get { return this._Rounds; }
                set
                {
                    if (this._Rounds != value)
                    {
                        this.ValidateProperty("Rounds", value);
                        this._Rounds = value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Rounds");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick example to point you in the right direction but add to your ViewModel your possible options:

```
private readonly IEnumerable<int> roundOptions = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
public IEnumerable<int> RoundOptions
{
    get
    {
        return roundOptions;
    }
}
```

And then bind your xaml:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Rounds, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding RoundOptions}" />
```

This adds to the ComboBox the possible options contained in `RoundOptions` and then says to keep the `Rounds` variable sync'd between the ViewModel and the UI using a `TwoWay` binding. If round options is going to be updated in the ViewModel to different sets of options I'd use an `ObservableCollection` instead.

At least that's based on your question text. I don't know what the `[MultipleChoice]` attribute is intended for.

Comment: @McGarnagle - I like it. Edited.